# MPI_TYPE_VECTOR

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to use MPI_TYPE_VECTOR in order to exchange information between ghosts cells of a 2D computational domain. The test case is the following:

The topology is made of two blocks in the vertical direction and one block in the other directions. The objective is to fill the ghost cells of each block with the corresponding cells of the neighbor block.

If I don't use the derived types from MPI, the communications are just fine.

```
    PROGRAM test

      USE mpi

      IMPLICIT NONE

      INTEGER*4, PARAMETER :: kim = 3  ! Number of cells (horizontal)
     &     , kjm = 2  ! Number of cells (vertical)
     &     , is  = 1  ! Number of ghost cells 

      INTEGER*4, DIMENSION(1-is:kim+is,1-is:kjm+is)
     &     :: vect2d  ! 2D vector representing the computational domain

      INTEGER*4 :: i, j

!     MPI Parameters

      INTEGER*4, PARAMETER :: ndims = 2 
      INTEGER*4 :: mpicode      
      INTEGER*4 :: nb_procs     
      INTEGER*4 :: rank         
      INTEGER*4 :: comm         
      INTEGER*4 :: etiquette = 100 
      INTEGER*4, DIMENSION (ndims) :: dims 
      INTEGER*4, DIMENSION (ndims) :: coords 
      LOGICAL, DIMENSION (ndims) :: periods 
      LOGICAL :: reorganisation 
      INTEGER, DIMENSION(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: statut 
      INTEGER*4, DIMENSION (2*ndims) :: neighbors 
      INTEGER*4 :: type_column 

! Initialisation MPI

      CALL MPI_INIT (mpicode)
      CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, nb_procs, mpicode)
      CALL MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, mpicode)

      dims(1) = 1
      dims(2) = 2

      periods = .FALSE.
      reorganisation = .FALSE.

      CALL MPI_CART_CREATE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, ndims, dims, periods,
     &     reorganisation, comm, mpicode)
      CALL MPI_CART_COORDS (comm, rank, ndims, coords, mpicode)

      CALL MPI_CART_SHIFT (comm, 0, 1, neighbors(1), neighbors(2),
     &     mpicode)
      CALL MPI_CART_SHIFT (comm, 1, 1, neighbors(3), neighbors(4),
     &     mpicode)

! Initialisation domain

      DO i = 1-is, kim+is
         DO j = 1-is, kjm +is

            vect2d(i,j) = rank

         END DO
      END DO

! Communications
!     Without vector type

      DO i = 1, kim

           CALL MPI_RECV (vect2d(i,1-is:0),
     &         size(vect2d(i,1-is:0)),
     &         MPI_INTEGER, neighbors(3), etiquette, comm,
     &         statut, mpicode)

           CALL MPI_SEND (vect2d(i,kjm+1-is:kjm),
     &          size(vect2d(i,kjm+1-is:kjm)),
     &          MPI_INTEGER, neighbors(4), etiquette, comm,
     &          mpicode)

           CALL MPI_RECV (vect2d(i,kjm+1:kjm+is),
     &          size(vect2d(i,kjm+1:kjm+is)),
     &          MPI_INTEGER, neighbors(4), etiquette, comm,
     &          statut, mpicode)

           CALL MPI_SEND (vect2d(i,1:is),
     &          size(vect2d(i,1:is)),
     &          MPI_INTEGER, neighbors(3), etiquette, comm,
     &          mpicode)

        END DO

! Write


      OPEN (10,
     &     file = "test.dat",
     &     form = "formatted",
     &     status = "unknown")

      IF (rank .EQ.1 ) WRITE(10,*) vect2D

      CLOSE(10)

      CALL MPI_FINALIZE(mpicode)

      END PROGRAM test
```

In this case the first line of the upper block is [10001], so the ghost cells are filled with the value of the lower block.

With MPI_TYPE_VECTOR

```
      PROGRAM test

      USE mpi

      IMPLICIT NONE

      INTEGER*4, PARAMETER :: kim = 3  ! Number of cells (horizontal)
     &     , kjm = 2  ! Number of cells (vertical)
     &     , is  = 1  ! Number of ghost cells 

      INTEGER*4, DIMENSION(1-is:kim+is,1-is:kjm+is)
     &     :: vect2d  ! 2D vector representing the computational domain

      INTEGER*4 :: i, j

!     MPI Parameters

      INTEGER*4, PARAMETER :: ndims = 2 
      INTEGER*4 :: mpicode      
      INTEGER*4 :: nb_procs     
      INTEGER*4 :: rank         
      INTEGER*4 :: comm         
      INTEGER*4 :: etiquette = 100 
      INTEGER*4, DIMENSION (ndims) :: dims 
      INTEGER*4, DIMENSION (ndims) :: coords 
      LOGICAL, DIMENSION (ndims) :: periods 
      LOGICAL :: reorganisation 
      INTEGER, DIMENSION(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: statut 
      INTEGER*4, DIMENSION (2*ndims) :: neighbors 
      INTEGER*4 :: type_column 

!------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Initialisation MPI

      CALL MPI_INIT (mpicode)
      CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, nb_procs, mpicode)
      CALL MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, mpicode)

      dims(1) = 1
      dims(2) = 2

      periods = .FALSE.
      reorganisation = .FALSE.

      CALL MPI_CART_CREATE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, ndims, dims, periods,
     &     reorganisation, comm, mpicode)
      CALL MPI_CART_COORDS (comm, rank, ndims, coords, mpicode)

      CALL MPI_CART_SHIFT (comm, 0, 1, neighbors(1), neighbors(2),
     &     mpicode)
      CALL MPI_CART_SHIFT (comm, 1, 1, neighbors(3), neighbors(4),
     &     mpicode)

      CALL MPI_TYPE_VECTOR(is, 1, (kim+2*is),
     &     MPI_INTEGER, type_column, mpicode)

      CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(type_column, mpicode)

!------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Initialisation domain

      DO i = 1-is, kim+is
         DO j = 1-is, kjm +is

            vect2d(i,j) = rank

         END DO
      END DO

!------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Communications

!     With vector type

      DO i = 1, kim

         CALL MPI_RECV (vect2d(j,1-is),
     &        1,
     &        type_column, neighbors(3), etiquette, comm,
     &        statut, mpicode)

         CALL MPI_SEND (vect2d(i,kjm+1-is),
     &        1,
     &        type_column, neighbors(4), etiquette, comm,
     &        mpicode)


         CALL MPI_RECV (vect2d(i,kjm+1),
     &        1,
     &        type_column, neighbors(4), etiquette, comm,
     &        statut, mpicode)

         CALL MPI_SEND (vect2d(i,1),
     &        1,
     &        type_column, neighbors(3), etiquette, comm,
     &        mpicode)

       END DO


!------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Write


      OPEN (10,
     &     file = "test.dat",
     &     form = "formatted",
     &     status = "unknown")

      IF (rank .EQ.1 ) WRITE(10,*) vect2D

      CLOSE(10)

      CALL MPI_FINALIZE(mpicode)

      END PROGRAM test
```

In this case the output isn't the expected one, as I obtain : [11110]
I suppose that it is from the definition of my type_column, but I cannot figure it out ... so any help and explanation is welcome !

Thanks

EDIT : Here is the domain associated with the matrix in the test case

**(0,3) | (1,3) | (2,3) | (3,3) | (4,3)**

**(0,2) |** (1,2) | (2,2) | (3,2) **| (4,2)**

**(0,1) |** (1,1) | (2,1) | (3,1) **| (4,1)**

**(0,0) | (1,0) | (2,0) | (3,0) | (4,0)**

For what I understood, the memory disposition associated with this matrix is :

**(0,0) | (1,0) | (2,0) | (3,0) | (4,0)**|**(0,1) |** (1,1) | (2,1) | (3,1) **| (4,1)** ...

Comment: Columns in Fortran are contiguous. To define a vector datatype that spans `is` rows, the `count` argument to `MPI_TYPE_VECTOR` (the first one) should be equal to the number of columns in a row, not to `is`, while `blocklength` should be equal to `is`.

Comment: In the test case, the two first arguments of MPI_TYPE_VECTOR are equal to one, so switching won't solve the problem. And in my case, I thought the matrix was represented as follows :    
a1,1 | a2,1 | a 3,1| a1,2 | a2,2 | a3,2|a1,3 | a2,3 | a3,3

Are you sure about the two first arguments ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. `CALL MPI_TYPE_VECTOR(is, 1, (kim+2*is), ...` creates a vector of one block (`is = 1`) of one element and stride of `(kim+2*is)`. You are sending one element of that datatype == one integer element from the data array.

Comment: Okay, but how can we explain that this test case isn't working whereas the two first arguments are identical ? Even if I would have been wrong, this should lead to the same results.

Comment: There is a bug in your vector code - in the first receive you specify "j" when I guess you mean "i".

Answer (score 1):

The main confusion here is that you have used the terminology "column", but the way you have drawn the arrays means that you are actually swapping rows. Let's stick with your convention for drawing the arrays and call the directions "horizontal" (increasing value of first index "i") and "vertical" (increasing value of second index "j") to avoid confusion.

If we fix your i <-> j bug as mentioned in the comments then your code works. However, the whole point about using vectors is to avoid multiple sends so, as written, your vector code doesn't improve on using basic datatypes. For the pattern shown above then, at least for a single-depth halo, you could just send contiguous data with count=kim. For deeper halos you would need a vector type with count=is, blocksize=kim and stride=kim+2*is. Having done this, you would use count=1 when sending and receiving and you transfer all the halo with a single call.

For halo swaps in the horizontal direction (i.e. swapping vertical halos) then you always need a vector type with count=kjm, blocksize=is and stride=km+2*is. Again, use count=1 when sending and receiving.

There are other issues with issuing the receives first (potential deadlock for periodic boundary conditions) which can't be entirely solved by putting the sends first (since MPI_Send could be implemented synchronously) but for your particular test code the solution lies in being consistent with terminology and using appropriate vector types.